# Date of Next Inspection for REAC data

Tags: data.gov

Is there a dataset that will provide me with the date of the next (upcoming) inspection for REAC (HUD)? The basic data is available via this link, https://hudapps.hud.gov/public/pass/scheduler/publicscheduler.action; however it is not available with the other property data (name, address, etc.) that can be downloaded from HUD's website.

Comment: Does HUD fall under data.gov? I reckon most gov data does, just wondering if that tag could be better or worse.